# Modification of non-creatable array value

Tags: perl

Running this Perl code gives me the error:

> Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -1 at
>   update.pl line 85,  line 1.

Line 85 is the one that has `$line[$r] .= $_`. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
my $loc =  '../update/panden.txt';
my $r   = -1;
my @line;

open (R, $loc) || die "$!";

while ( <R> ) {
   $_ =~ s/NULL//g;
   $r++ if ( $_ =~ /^"[0-9]{2,10}"\|"/ );
   $line[$r] .= $_;    # Line 85
   my $ref = $_;
}

close R;
```

Comment: Please show the contents of `panden.txt`. There is likely to be a much better, more Perlish way to do this.

Comment: You get that error when using a negative subscript whose magnitude (absolute value) is greater-than or equal to the size of the array.

Answer (score 3):

At a guess - your regex isn't matching, therefore `$r` is still `-1` and you've an empty array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @list;

$list[-1] = 1;
```

Gives you the same error. That implies that:

```
$_ =~ /^"[0-9]{2,10}"\|"/
```

Doesn't match for the first line of your input.

The point of negative indices in an array is a special case - it means 'count from the end' - so `$array[-1]` is the last element. But that doesn't really make sense when you have an empty array.

It *would* work if you've got an array that's already been populated, but I'd suggest based on your program logic - it *shouldn't*, and so setting it to `-1` with the assumption that you'll be incrementing it later is actually asking for trouble in the first place.